# Resharper "Surround With" replacing selected text

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (Update 1) with Resharper Ultimate 10.0.2.

Whenever I am trying to surround a piece of selected text using `Ctrl+K, S`, the entire selection is replaced with an empty region. I have detected that this is caused because of Resharper (as disabling the same fixes the issue).

Is there a way to fix this that doesn't involve disabling Resharper?

P.S.: I know surrounding can also be done using `Ctrl+E, U`, but I am kind of used to using `Ctrl+K, S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you faced [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-452582). Try installing [ReSharper 10.1 EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP) - such issue is marked as "Fixed" there.